# JS: XML insertBefore createElement

Tags: javascript, xml

I have an xml payload

```
   <myXML>
      <ctx>
       <recipient>
          <CardNumber>1245</CardNumber>
          <age>16</age>
          <height>180</height>          
       </recipient>
      </ctx>
   </myXML>


  var xmlDoc = DOMDocument.fromXMLString(message).getElementsByTagName("myXML")[0].toXMLString();
```

which basically outputs starting from the ctx node.

I want to add a new node/element at a specific location using the insertBefore, but it isnt working for me, whas the correct method?

ref - https://experienceleague.adobe.com/developer/campaign-api/api/m-DOMNode-insertBefore.html

```
  xmlDoc.insertBefore("<email>david@garcia.com</email>","<CardNumber>");
```

do I have to create the element? how do I insert it at a specific location? using `insertBefore`

```
  var email = xmlDoc.createElement("email");
      email.textContent = "david@garcia.com";
      email.appendChild(ctx)
```

Here is how I achieved it

```
var myxml = <myXML>

       <recipient>
          <CardNumber>1245</CardNumber>
          <age>16</age>
          <height>180</height>          
       </recipient>
       <recipient2>
          <CardNumber1>1245</CardNumber1>
          <age>16</age>
          <height>180</height>          
       </recipient2>       
  
   </myXML>;

  var xmlDoc = new DOMDocument.fromXMLString(myxml);
  var root = xmlDoc.root;
  
    var ctx = xmlDoc.createElement("ctx");
  root.appendChild(ctx);
  
  var emailElem = xmlDoc.createElement("email");
  emailElem.textContent = "david@garcia.com";
  var parent = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CardNumber")[0].parentNode;
  var email = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CardNumber")[0];
  
  parent.insertBefore(emailElem, email);
  
logInfo(xmlDoc.toXMLString())
```

The output is

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<myXML>
  <recipient>
    <email>david@garcia.com</email>
    <CardNumber>1245</CardNumber>
    <age>16</age>
    <height>180</height>
  </recipient>
  <recipient2>
    <CardNumber1>1245</CardNumber1>
    <age>16</age>
    <height>180</height>
  </recipient2>
  <ctx/>
</myXML>
```

Comment: Is that your actual XML payload? Because that's neither XML nor JS, it's both at the same time, and as such, can't run as either. Also note that you can't create XML elements with `createElement`, you'll need to use `createElementNS` with the appropriate namespace, because you're not creating DOM nodes for an HTML document.

Comment: you don't want to work with the XML string, you want to work with an XML document

Comment: The arguments to `insertBefore()` are nodes, not strings.    You'll be better off using  MDN docs in general (here's what MDN has for [`insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)) than that Adobe reference you've linked to.

Comment: @kjhughes that helped me complete it.

Comment: by the way, this application uses ecma5 1.8.5 SpiderMonkey engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no experience using Abode Campaign.

Using DOM methods in a browser or other environment that supports DOM manipulation, you can do something like the following, which inserts a `Node`, not text. See [MDN's Node: insertBefore() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore).

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xml = parser.parseFromString(`<myXML>
      <ctx>
       <recipient>
          <CardNumber>1245</CardNumber>
          <age>16</age>
          <height>180</height>          
       </recipient>
      </ctx>
   </myXML>`, "text/xml");

var email = xml.createElement("email");
email.textContent = "david@garcia.com";

xml.querySelector("recipient")
.insertBefore(
  email, 
  xml.querySelector("recipient")
 .firstElementChild
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use query selector with CSS selectors to fetch element nodes.

Creating a node in DOM consists of two parts. You create the node using a document method and append/insert the node using a method of the node.

Classic (older) DOM methods like `appendChild()` or `insertBefore()` require a node argument. However modern DOM methods like `append()`/`before()`/`after()` will create text nodes for string arguments and take multiple arguments.

`before()` allows to shorten `insertBefore()` calls:

`target.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, target)` → `target.before(newNode)`

```js
const xmlDocument = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(
   `<myXML>
     <ctx>
       <recipient>
         <CardNumber>1245</CardNumber>
         <age>16</age>
         <height>180</height>          
       </recipient>
     </ctx>
   </myXML>`, 
   "text/xml"
);

// fetch the CardNumber element
const recipientCardNumber = xmlDocument.querySelector('recipient > CardNumber');

// create the new element node
const email = xmlDocument.createElement("email");
// append text content
email.append("david@garcia.com");

// insert new node before fetched CardNumber element
recipientCardNumber.before(email);

document.querySelector('#output').value = 
  (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlDocument);
```

```css
textarea {
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="output"></textarea>
```